# software which can stream any flv file

Tags: windows, desktop-application, streaming-flv-video

I know this is not programming related, but I have a scenario.

Each video streaming site has a flash video plugin and upon viewing the source I can find the link of the flv file it is streaming. Now I wanted to make an application or work on an existing one, where I can copy and paste the url of the flv file and it streams it for me. Something like an application which can stream flash videos for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side you can use this flash application to render the flv (works on any flv file) http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ . Needs a license for commercial use (quite cheap).

On the server side you have to build an application which will stream flv files - but i guess that, if you want to use existing online flv files, you don't need this part.

Answer (score 1):

Take an [opensource flv player](http://www.osflv.com/Download.html) and plug it into your website and put the url of the flv files you want to stream.

Should work in most cases, in cases it won't work, you have the source code, so change it to overcome any issues :).

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe Flash or the Flex SDK.

Comment: can you elaborate on it. Do you mean i make a web app or Flex App which incorporates a flash player and the url which i supply?

Comment: yea. theres a flash video component you can use.